# ASP MVC Route not firing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am having a bit of trouble getting my routing working correctly.  I am needing to support IIS 5.1, so I want to suffix the controller with .mvc, here is what I have currently:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}.mvc/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Home" }
        );
```

This fails.  If I remove the .mvc, it works as expected.  Also, weirdly enough if I add another path in between the controller and action, it works.  Like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}.mvc/Anything/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Home" }
        );
```

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Thanks in advance,
Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with code as below

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultWithExtension",
                url: "{controller}.mvc/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );            
        }
```

It works correctly. Please try those code in your application.

Answer (score 0):

IIS could be treating the request as a static file or another handler is receiving and processing the request.

If this is the case, you'll need to add a handler mapping for the **.mvc** extension in IIS and ensure it's using ASP.NET.